# Issue with keras fit_generator epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm creating an LSTM Model for Text generation using Keras. As the dataset(around 25 novels,which has around 1.4 million words) I'm using can't be processed at once(An Memory issue with converting my outputs to_Categorical()) I created a custom generator function to read the Data in.

```
# Data generator for fit and evaluate
def generator(batch_size):
    start = 0
    end = batch_size
    while True:
      x = sequences[start:end,:-1]
      #print(x)
      y = sequences[start:end,-1]
      y = to_categorical(y, num_classes=vocab_size)
      #print(y)
      yield x, y
      if batch_size == len(lines):
        break;
      else:
        start += batch_size
        end += batch_size
```

when i excecute the model.fit() method, after 1 epoch is done training the following error is thrown.

```
UnknownError:  [_Derived_]  CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
in tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc(1459): 'cudnnSetTensorNdDescriptor( tensor_desc.get(), data_type, sizeof(dims) / sizeof(dims[0]), dims, strides)'
     [[{{node CudnnRNN}}]]
     [[sequential/lstm/StatefulPartitionedCall]] [Op:__inference_train_function_25138]

Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function -> train_function
```

does anyone know how to solve this issue ? Thanks

Comment: Did you solve the problem? What is the version of the tensorflow you are using? Is it possible to share a reproducible code?

Answer (score 0):

From many sources in the Internet, this issue seems to occur while using `LSTM Layer` along with `Masking Layer` and while training on `GPU`.

Mentioned below can be the workarounds for this problem:

1. If you can compromise on speed, you can Train your `Model` on `CPU` rather than on `GPU`. It works without any error.
2. As per [this comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33069#issuecomment-539038068), please check if your `Input Sequences` comprises of all Zeros, as the `Masking Layer` may mask all the `Inputs`
3. If possible, you can Disable the `Eager Execution`. As per [this comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33148#issuecomment-622998846), it works without any error.
4. Instead of using a Masking Layer, you can try the alternatives mentioned in [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/masking_and_padding#masking)

   a. Adding the argument, `mask_zero = True` to the `Embedding Layer`. or

   b. Pass a mask argument manually when calling layers that support this argument
5. Last solution can be to remove `Masking Layer`, if that is possible.

If none of the above workaround solves your problem, Google Tensorflow Team is working to resolve this error. We may have to wait till that is fixed.

Hope this information helps. Happy Learning!